# How can I delete all rows containing given text that could be in any column within the row?

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to be able to delete all rows in a Google Spreadsheets where a given text string exists anywhere in the row. The text being searched for could be in any cell in the row, and also could be part of a longer string within the row cell e.g. "xxxx [text being searched for] yyy".

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand your question. Have you tried using the search and replace feature? I believe there's an add on for that if sheets doesn't have it by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have not tagged this [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) but with a script is the only way to delete rows 'automatically'. However 'manually' is not tedious. Assumimg your range of interest is confined to ColumnsA:Z, in say AA1 please try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(--not(iserror(SEARCH("text",A1:Z1)))))
```

and copy it down to suit, where `text` above represents whatever the offending string is.

This is case insensitive.

Then filter ColumnA:A to select rows that have a numeric value (not `0`) and delete these.

[SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669)
[NOT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093305)
[ISERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349)
[SEARCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154)